# How to upload an image to a folder and pass its path to a view function in django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, file-upload, image-upload

I want to upload an image file using an input file tag from a django template. Then i want to do 2 things:
1) First i want to store the uploaded image in a directory in my project. I want to upload the file in img directory under static directory in my app so to access it easily.
2) Second i want to send the filename of this newly stored image to a view function called `detect_im()`

**TEMPLATE:**

```
<form style="display:inline-block;">
      <input type="file" class="form-control-file">
      <input type="submit" value="Upload"=>
</form>
```

**VIEW FUNCTION in views.py**

```
def detect_im(request):
    haar_file = 'C:\\Users\\Aayush\\ev_manage\\face_detector\\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'
    datasets = 'datasets\\'
    myid = random.randint(1111, 9999)

    path = "C:\\Users\\Aayush\\ev_manage\\face_detector\\" + datasets + str(myid)
    if not os.path.isdir(path):
        os.mkdir(path)

    (width, height) = (130, 100)
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(haar_file)


    filename = ""  //I WANT THE STORED FILE NAME VALUE HERE TO COMPLETE THE PATH FOR FURTHER DETECTION PROCESS BY OPENCV.


    image_path = "C:\\Users\\Aayush\\ev_manage\\face_detector\\static\\img\\" + filename

    count = 1
    while count < 30:
        im = cv2.imread(image_path)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 4)
        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
            face = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
            face_resize = cv2.resize(face, (width, height))
            cv2.imwrite('% s/% s.png' % (path, count), face_resize)
        count += 1

        key = cv2.waitKey(10)
        if key == 27:
            break

    return render(request, 'add_dataset.html', {'uid': myid})
```

The final flow should be like that, user adds the image and click on upload then image gets uploaded to directory and detect_im() function is called with the filename and that filename is used in the path variable for the opencv to detect the face out of it.

Thanks for reading. Please post an answer with at least some code additions because i am a rookie in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> upload an image file using an input file tag from a django template and
>   store the uploaded image in a directory in my project

Try to use Pillow:

First, install the package

```
pip3 install Pillow
```

Next, create a field and function

in your models.py:

```py
# models.py 
import os

from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now as timezone_now
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


def upload_to(instance, filename):
    now = timezone_now()
    base, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    ext = ext.lower()
    return f"(your_dir)/{now:%Y/%m/%Y%m%d%H%M%S}{ext}"
    # Do add the date as it prevents the same file name from occuring twice
    # the ext is reserved for the file type and don't remove it


class MyExampleClass(models.Model):
    ...
    picture = models.ImageField(_("Picture"), upload_to=upload_to, blank=True, null=True)
```

Then, create a form to upload the image:

```py
# forms.py 
from django import forms


class MyExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyExampleClass
        fields = ["picture"]
```

Remember to render it in a view and your url:

```py
# views.py 
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from .forms import MyExampleForm


def add_image(request):
    form = MyExampleForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MyExampleForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect("")
    else:
        return render(request, "myexamplehtml.html", {"form": form})

# quotes/urls.py
from django.urls import path

from .views import MyExampleView

urlpatterns = [
    path('foobar/', add_image, name='myexampleview'),
]
```

Finally, add it in your HTML file:

```
{% block content %}
    <form method="post" action="your_url" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

About the second part, I think that you can access your user's variable like this:

```py
MyExampleModel._meta.get_field('picture')
```

and then put this code into wherever you want it to function

Hope that this works!

Comment: getting this error ``` MyExampleForm object has no attribute save ```

Comment: Please see this i have followed your instructions but getting the error
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59837348

Comment: I think the save function IS limited to class-based views, which somebody covered it on your question. Sorry that I was unable to clarify it at the beginning 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59837348/unable-to-upload-image-to-django-project-getting-form-object-has-no-attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Path of the uploaded file by following this...

```
#myImage is your Model
#image is your Model field

myImage.save()
got_url = Image.image.url

print(got_url)
```

Answer link :  [I am wondering how can we get path of uploaded Image (imageUrl) in views.py file in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66649707/i-am-wondering-how-can-we-get-path-of-uploaded-image-imageurl-in-views-py-file)