# Unable to upload image to Django Project, getting Form object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, sqlite, django-forms

I am trying to upload an image file through a file input from a template. I have followed all the instructions but getting this error when attaching the file and clicking on submit.

```
AttributeError: 'PicUpForm' object has no attribute 'save'
```

and hence my image is not uploading to the specified directory as well as the record is not inserting into my sqlitedb

FOLLOWING ARE ALL THE NECESSARY CODES I HAVE USED:

**views.py**

```
def add_image(request):
    form = PicUpForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PicUpForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect("")
    else:
        return render(request, "sample.html", {"form": form})
```

**forms.py**

```
class PicUpForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = PicUpClass
        fields = [model.picture]
    picture = forms.ImageField(label='File')
```

**models.py**

```
def upload_to(instance, filename):
    now = timezone_now()
    base, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    ext = ext.lower()
    return f"C:/Users/Aayush/ev_manage/face_detector/static/img/{now:%Y/%m/%Y%m%d%H%M%S}{ext}"



class PicUpClass(models.Model):
    picture = models.ImageField(_("picture"), upload_to=upload_to, blank=True, null=True)
```

**sample.html**

```
{% block content %}
{% load static %}
    <form method="post" action="/picup" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

```
...
path('picup', views.add_image, name='picup'),
```

Also i have run the makemigrations and migrate commands after creating the model as required. Please help me as i am a rookie in Python and very importantly need to complete this feature

Comment: It should be a `ModelForm`, so `PicUpForm(forms.ModelForm):` Fruthermore please use a string as field, so `fields = ['picture']`.

Comment: tried this now getting
```
NoReverseMatch at /picup
Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Comment: that is due to the `return redirect("")`, you should pass the name of a view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `PicUpForm` is *not* a `ModelForm`, hence it will not take the `Meta` into account at all. Note that the fields should be a list of strings, so you should rewrite the form to:

```
class PicUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PicUpClass
        fields = ['picture']
```

Note that in your view, for the `redirect(..)` you need to pass the *name* of a view, so:

```
def add_image(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PicUpForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('name-of-view')
    else:
        form = PicUpForm()
    return render(request, 'sample.html', {'form': form})
```

Here you need to replace *`name-of-view`* with the name of a view.

If the view contains a parameter, you can pass this as a named parameter, for example here if your view has a `picture_id` parameter (if it has another parameter, then of course you should change the name of the parameter):

```
def add_image(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PicUpForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            picup = form.save()
            return redirect('name-of-view', picture_id=picup.pk)
    else:
        form = PicUpForm()
    return render(request, 'sample.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: no luck. now getting the error

NoReverseMatch at /picup
Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: hey @willem can u please help me with more one thing . at the line return redirect('name of view') i also want to send a parameter containing the value of inserted record picture field that contains the path. i want to access that path in another view function and template. please can u??

Comment: @AayushGupta: see edit: if your view for example has a `picture_id` parameter, you can use a named parameter.

Comment: but i want to access the "picture" field value not the id field

Comment: @AayushGupta: then it is `pickup.picture`. But you can *not* "encode" a picture in a URL. You should encode something that has an encoding (like a primary key, slug, etc.)