# I am wondering how can we get path of uploaded Image (imageUrl) in views.py file in Django

Tags: django-views

I want to get the path of the image which I uploaded in this views.py file.
For example, I am saving uploaded image as,   imageInfo.save()

then how can I get path of imageInfo, as it is being saved in the database,
I am using the default "sqlite3" in my project??
I am thankful for you if you could help me in this

```
def studentImageView(request):
    img = studentImage.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        imageForm = request.FILES.getlist('images')
        for item in imageForm:
            print('item---------\n', item)
            imageInfo = studentImage.objects.create(image=item,)
            imageInfo.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Images Added successfully')
    else:
        imageForm = studentImageForm()
    context={
        'img': img,
    }
    return render(request, 'teacherApp/image.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

i got the url by adding

```
imageInfo.save()
got_url = imageInfo.image.url

print(got_url)
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28541226)

Comment: @AmitVerma Please pay attention. This is actually an answer to the question...